# Upsell product disappear after adding to Cart - CE 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, up-sells

product X has 1 upsell product Y and Y is displaying on the product page of X. After adding Y to the basket, it disappear as upsell product on product page X.

Does anybody know how to display upsell products on product page constantly whether the product is added to the basket or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. It's a feature.
You don't see as upsells or cross-sells the products that you already have in the cart.
From the marketing poit of view it's a better approach.
but if you insist in having them always displayed you need to rewrite the method `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell::_prepareData` and remove this

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
);
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right and it's good feature as it is but I need different approach to upsell products. Cheers J